# Getting aoData.push error on jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable plugin for display data but getting this error: `aoData.push is not a function` when I am passing my custom variable to datatable.

Any idea about this error?

### Here is my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#table').DataTable({

        "processing": true, // Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, // Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/invite_instagrammers/GetInstagrammersData')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        // "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        //     aoData.push({name: "pid", value: '15'});
        // },

        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "Loading records..."
        },

        // Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [-1], // Last column
            "orderable": false, // Set not orderable
        }, ],

    });

    $('.search-inp').on( 'keyup click', function () {   // For text boxes
        var i = $(this).attr('data-column');  // Getting column index
        var v = $(this).val();  // Getting search input value
        table.columns(i).search(v).draw();
    });
    $('.search-inp').on( 'change', function () {   // For select box
        var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
        var v = $(this).val();
        table.columns(i).search(v).draw();
    });
});

function reload_table() {
    table.ajax.reload(null, false); // Reload datatable ajax
}
```

and I have added this code to my datatable:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push({name: "pid", value: '15'});
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Option `fnServerParams` is for older version of jQuery DataTables 1.9. Since you're using 1.10, use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option instead as shown below:

```js
 table = $('#table').DataTable({
        "processing": true, // Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, // Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/invite_instagrammers/GetInstagrammersData')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {
               "pid": "15"
            }
        },

        // ... skipped ...
```

Comment: And as supplemental info, see this -> https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28002/fnserverparams-for-datatables-1-10

Answer (score 0):

"data":{
        "foo":"bar"
}

is for static data parameters, if you want to send dynamic data let's say something in an input value please use this on

```
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d.OrderNo =  $('#OrderNo').val();
                }
```